# PHP Using a while loop to fetch items, using a dynamic select function?

Tags: php, mysql

Okay, I've never ever used dynamic functions, not sure why, I've never liked using explode(), implode(), etc.

but I've tried it out, and something went wrong.

```
    public function fetch($table, array $criteria = null)
    {
        // The query base
        $query = "SELECT * FROM $table";

        // Start checking
        if ($criteria) {
            $query .= ' WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', array_map(function($column) {
                return "$column = ?";
            }, array_keys($criteria)));
        }

        $check = $this->pdo->prepare($query) or die('An error has occurred with the following message:' . $query);
        $check->execute(array_values($criteria));

        $fetch = $check->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        return $fetch;
    }
```

This is my query.

Basically I will return the variable `$fetch` which holds the fetch method.

and then somewhere, where I want to use the while loop to fetch data, I will use that:

```
$r = new Database();

while ($row = $r->fetch("argonite_servers", array("server_map" => "Wilderness")))
{
    echo $row['server_map'];
}
```

Now, I am not getting any errors, but the browser is loading and loading forever, and eventually will get stuck due to lack of memory.

That's because the loop is running and running without stopping.
Why is it doing this? How can I get this dynamic query to work?

EDIT:

```
$r = new Database();
$q = $r->fetch("argonite_servers", array("server_map" => "Wilderness"));

while ($row = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    echo $row['server_map'];
}
```

Comment: `foreach ($r->fetch(....) as $item ) {}`

Answer (score 1):

this is because you call your fetch function in a loop and it re-starts the query every time. You need to call the $check->fetch() in loop instead.

or in other words, if your fetch function (which should probably have a different name) would return $check, then on the returned object you should call fetch() in a loop:

```
$r = new Database();
$q = $r->fetch(...);
while($q->fetch()){...}
```

you also need to edit your fetch function to end like this:

```
    $check->execute(array_values($criteria));
    return $check;
}
```

Comment: Getting atal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object , read my edit

Comment: yes because you need to change your fetch function so it's end should look like this: $check->execute(array_values($criteria));return $check}

Answer (score 1):

One nice feature of PDO is that the `PDOStatement` implements the `Traversable`. This means you can iterate it directly:

```
// `$check` is a `PDOStatement` object
$check = $this->pdo->prepare($query) or die('An error has occurred with the following message:' . $query);
$check->execute(array_values($criteria));

$check->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

return $check;
```

Use it:

```
$statement = $r->fetch("argonite_servers", array("server_map" => "Wilderness"));
foreach ($statement as $row) {

}
```

Comment: What if I want to fetch one item, without loops?

Comment: just call `$row = $statement->fetch();`